# Exercise 3.6.e from Schechter's book "Handbook of analysis and its foundations"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $\preceq$ be a reflexive relation on a set $X$ and let $\prec$ be the corresponding irreflexive relation. Then

(i) $\preceq$ is symmetric if and only if $\prec$ is symmetric, and

(ii) $\preceq$ is transitive if and only if $\prec$ is transitive.

---

It's easy exercise, but i can't see why necessity in (ii) is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(ii) is false. If $X=\{a,b\}$ and $\preceq$ satisfies $x\preceq y$
for all $x$ and $y$, then $\preceq$ is transitive but $a\prec b\prec a$ and $a\not\prec a$ so that $\prec $ is not transitive.